# Spawning a world in Gazebo while connected to the internet results in tf jumps in time

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-11

Simply spawning a world in Gazebo 11 with a ROS 2 launcher (quoted at the end of this question) gives me the following error:

```
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1702564069.868177023] [gazebo]: New subscription discovered on topic '/clock', requesting incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY
```

If I then spawn my robot then all hell breaks loose since the tf tree timings are all messed up, i.e.:

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame wheel_right_link at time 57.086000 according to authority Authority undetectable
[component_container_isolated-3] Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
[component_container_isolated-3]          at line 292 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
[component_container_isolated-3] [WARN] [1702564890.894654043] [tf2_buffer]: Detected jump back in time. Clearing TF buffer.
```

The strange thing is that if I disable my ethernet interface (essentially pull the ethernet plug from my pc), everything is ok. How may I solve this issue?

Edit: this behaviour is not [deterministic](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/915/161/e0a.gif)

```python
from os.path import join
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration


def generate_launch_description():

  # ============================================================================
  world = join(a_pkg_name, "worlds", "world_name.world")

  gazebo_ros_dir = get_package_share_directory("gazebo_ros")

  # ============================================================================
  # Gazebo server
  gzserver_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
      PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
          join(gazebo_ros_dir, "launch", "gzserver.launch.py")
      ),
      launch_arguments={"world": world}.items(),
  )

  # ============================================================================
  # Gazebo client
  gzclient_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
      PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
          join(gazebo_ros_dir, "launch", "gzclient.launch.py")
      )
  )

  # ============================================================================
  return LaunchDescription([gzserver_cmd, gzclient_cmd])
```

Gazebo version: 11.10.2

Answer (score 0):

```
    parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description_raw,'use_sim_time': True}],
```

adding the line above to my nodes definition worked for me.

Comment: Maybe [edit] your answer to show where this line would be inserted, in a small example?